# Google App script - email quota

Tags: email, google-apps-script, quota

i am using Google form with spreadsheet. I have a script in the spreadsheet: it sends a notification as soon as a form is submitted.
the Google daily quota is set to 100 but at every submission my quota is decreased by 2 and not by 1. I checked it with method "MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()".
I am sure i have only one recipient.
Does anybody know the reason ?
thank
Michele

Comment: Please share the code.  I use MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota(); a lot and I've never seen that problem.

Comment: Try making yourself the only recipient.  Then you'll see how many emails your receiving.

Comment: If you have an editor of the Form other than yourself, then it's possible that two emails get sent.  Check your sent folder in your email do see if duplicate emails are being sent.

Comment: Have you been assigning clicks to buttons?  Perhaps with JQuery.  If you change the function name on a click it just assigns another listener to that event that ties to the assigned function but it doesn't remove the old assignment.  So you may need to unbind or in some other way remove the old assignments.